# NetSuite Advance pdf/html template

Tags: html, css, netsuite

i have a PO with both expense and item fields but need to pull only the epenses without inserting items on pdf template print out on NetSuite how to customise that? as i will need that template to print out the following from the transaction side without customizing many templates:

1. PO with just an Item
2. PO with just an Expense
3. PO with both Item and Expense

is there a specific standard functionality to only have one PO customised pulling both information on one template?

I have tried creating duplicate templates one for having only item, one for only having expenses and one for having both items and expenses.

i am expeting to have a way to only create one template that can print out and expense without item,item without expense, both item and expense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect whether you have items, expenses or both and modify the code for just the lines section of the template. The following is one where I did that for vendor bills:

```
<!-- start items/expenses -->


<#if (record.item?is_collection && record.item?has_content) || (record.expense?is_collection && record.expense?has_content)>
    <#assign sectionTitle = ''>
    <#assign headerRec = ''>
    <#assign idLabel = ''>
    <#assign qtyLabel = ''>

    <#if (record.item?is_collection && record.item?has_content) && (record.expense?is_collection && record.expense?has_content)>
        <#assign sectionTitle>${record.item@label}/${record.expense@label}</#assign>
        <#assign headerRec = record.item[0]>
        <#assign idLabel>${record.item[0].item@label}/${record.expense[0].account@label}</#assign>
        <#assign qtyLabel>${record.item[0].quantity@label}/${record.expense[0].memo@label}</#assign>

    <#elseif (record.item?is_collection && record.item?has_content)>
        <#assign sectionTitle = record.item@label>
        <#assign headerRec = record.item[0]>
        <#assign idLabel = record.item[0].item@label>
        <#assign qtyLabel = record.item[0].quantity@label>

    <#else>
        <#assign sectionTitle = record.expense@label>
        <#assign headerRec = record.expense[0]>
        <#assign idLabel = record.expense[0].account@label>
        <#assign qtyLabel = record.expense[0].memo@label>

    </#if>
<!-- both items and expenses machine have content -->



<span class="tabletitle">${sectionTitle}</span>

<table class="itemtable" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="3">${idLabel}</th>
    <th colspan="2">${qtyLabel}</th>
    <#if anyTax1 == true>
        <th align="right">${headerRec.taxrate1@label}</th>
        <th align="right">${headerRec.tax1amt@label}</th>
    </#if>
    <#if anyTax2 == true>
        <th align="right">${headerRec.taxrate2@label}</th>
    </#if>
    <th align="right">${headerRec.rate@label}</th>
    <th align="right">${headerRec.amount@label}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<#list record.item as item>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">${item.item}</td>
        <td colspan="2">${item.quantity}</td>
        
        <#if anyTax1 == true>
            <td align="right">${item.taxrate1}</td>
            <td align="right">${item.tax1amt}</td>
        </#if>
        <#if anyTax2 == true>
            <td align="right">${item.taxrate2}</td>
        </#if>
        <td align="right">${item.rate}</td>
        <td align="right">${item.amount}</td>
    </tr>
    </#list>
    <#list record.expense as expense>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">${expense.account}</td>
        <td colspan="2">${expense.memo}</td>
        <!-- expenses don't have quantities -->
        
        <#if anyTax1 == true>
            <td align="right">${expense.taxrate1}</td>
            <td align="right">${expense.tax1amt}</td>
        </#if>
        <#if anyTax2 == true>
            <td align="right">${expense.taxrate2}</td>
        </#if>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <!-- expenses don't have rates -->
        <td align="right">${expense.amount}</td>
    </tr>
    </#list>
</table>

</#if>
```

Comment: Thank you this is very much helpfull as from now i am able to print a pdf template with only expenses, i am able to print a template with only items, and also i am able to print a pdf template with both items and expenses inserted on transaction.

Comment: You're quite welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted then.